# Why jquery last-child not working in ie7 and 8

Tags: jquery

I want to run :last-child in ie 7. I know its not possible with only css but i added jquery Heres the following code in js

`$('#columncontainer > div:nth-child(even)').addClass("mar-right");`

and my html is

```
 <div id="columncontainer"> <div class="list-type"></div> <div class="list-type"></div> </div>
```

is there anything missing with ie7 and ie8 else this code is working every where in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support `nth-child`
See this link to view all browser compatibility

[BROWSER COMPATIBILITY](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38)

to solve this problem you can add a class with jquery and select it into your css file
like this:

```
$('#columncontainer:nth-child(even)').addClass('mar-right');
```

Comment: but this js fillde works can you tell me why.. http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aDtk4/1/

Answer (score 1):

:last-child doesn't work in IE7, try this instead:

```
$('#columncontainer').last().addClass('mar-right');
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and script .it works fine for me in ie7 and ie8
please refer the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ta9xu/1/

Comment: please can you tell me why the code isnt working in my localhost..<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/my_js.js"></script> I have these two headers

Comment: try with two froward slashes <script src="`//`code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> or use below
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`